# What is this icon?

Tags: usb, icons

On my new computer there are two USB ports with USB symbols containing an extra ball on the ball side of symbol. They are right next to the Ethernet port. The ports are not blue and do not have ss by them like the 3.0 ports but they have an extra ball on the symbol unlike 2.0 ports. What does this mean?

Comment: A search of your user manual could provide the answer.  Otherwise, please update with your make and model number.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot?

Comment: @user1306322 I think OP means the logo is silkscreened on the actual computer case.

Comment: A photo, then? Or anybody else who knows what the icon in question is, can you post a pic of it?

Comment: `USB symbols containing an extra ball on the ball side` Until we get a photo, I’m afraid [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/B8vQG.jpg) is what I keep picturing. (In the interests of good-taste, I decided to stop editing it at that point.) Normally, the USB plugs on the system are female; I don’t suppose these are male connectors are they? `:^D`

Answer (score 3):

I believe those are ports that continue to be powered even when the PC is shutdown.  Handy for charging other devices and similar tasks.

Comment: ’fraid not. Most powered USB ports tend not to have any sort of visible indication, but those that do will usually have something that is clearly associated with electricity like a lightning bolt, a positive and/or negative sign, or a number and/or V (for volts). Something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g1CpI.jpg). It doesn’t make sense to add an extra circle to designate a powered port, and on the **peripheral** side of the symbol no less.